# How to create CPack debian package with libstdc++6 3.4.26 included

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, c++17

I made a C++ application using the filesystem library, which is included in g++ since version 8. Now the problem is, the newest version on Ubuntu 18.04 is 7.5, so when i compile the application on Ubuntu 20.04 with g++ 9 and create a debian package, i can't run the installed application on Ubuntu 18.04 because the latest supported GLIBCXX version is 3.4.25, but it requires 3.4.26.

This is the error message i get when starting the application:
`` /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/libpine.so) ``

Is it possible to include "my" version in the debian package, so the application can be installed correctly on older versions of Ubuntu?

I already tried adding `libstdc++6 (>= 3.4.26)` to `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS` but it doesn't do anything.

These are my installs and configurations:

```
[...]
install(TARGETS pine
        RUNTIME DESTINATION "bin"
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
        LIBRARY DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}"
        COMPONENT libraries)

install(TARGETS taiga
        RUNTIME DESTINATION /opt/taiga/bin
        COMPONENT application)

install(DIRECTORY deps/pine/resources/
        DESTINATION /opt/taiga/bin/resources
        COMPONENT resources)

set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "Taiga")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VENDOR "masypw")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "Taiga - Test Application for pine")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "1")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY "/opt/taiga")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_MAINTAINER "masypw")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS "libvulkan1, libstdc++6 (>= 3.4.26)")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "DEB")
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL application libraries resources)
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_APPLICATION_DISPLAY_NAME "Taiga Application")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_LIBRARIES_DISPLAY_NAME "Libraries")
set(CPACK_COMPONENT_RESOURCES_DISPLAY_NAME "Resources")
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Including into a package a standard library (like libstdc++) is generally a **bad idea**. Normally, for distribute a package for a specific version of a standard library, you need to **build** the project against that specific version or a lower one. If you want to run your application on Ubuntu 18.04, which doesn't support C++ filesystems, then do not use this feature in your project.

Comment: Another option is to use ghc_filesystem which is a drop in replacement to std filesystem and is C++11 compatible.